# Interview - Minimum number of paper sheets needed to print products

Tags: algorithm

Given an array of paper products in which each product has an attribute name, width, and height, and given a sheet of paper that has width w and height h, write a program that returns the number of sheets of paper needed to print out the array of paper products.

Anyone has an idea how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the 2D bin packing problem, consult the literature (or your favourite search engine).

Answer (score 4):

This is a trick question.

The problem is called a "two-dimensional cutting stock problem" and it's not an easy one. People devote entire academic careers to it. There's a huge amount of literature and many commercial software packages. Just google "two-dimensional cutting stock problem" or "2d cutting stock problem" to appreciate its scope.

It is probably futile to look for the answer here. There's no "the" answer.